# How to route two get methods with same params in WebApi?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

In my `ApiController` i had one **GET** method which was returning some data from DB.

Now i have to enlarge that controller by adding **one more GET** method which will return data from same database but formatted in another way so the parameters **i'd pass to that method will be the same** as from the 1st one.

I was trying to do the following:

```
Public Class CshController
    Inherits ApiController

    Public Function GetValoriCsh(ByVal npv As String, ByVal nc As String) As IEnumerable(Of Cshlvl)
        Dim csh As Cshlvl = New Cshlvl
        Return csh.ValoreCsh(npv, nc)
    End Function

    Public Function GetOperazioni(ByVal npv As String, ByVal nc As String) As IEnumerable(Of OperazioniCsh)
        Dim operazioni As OperazioniCsh = New OperazioniCsh
        Return operazioni.OperazioniCsh(npv, nc)
    End Function


End Class
```

So here come the issue, the api fails as there are two method which require same parameters so it doesn't know how to chose which i would to use.

actually i'm calling the following api by the following url api/csh/ is it possible in some way by calling api/csh/ to get data from GetValoriCsh and like by calling something like api/csh/operazioni/ to get data from GetOperazioni?

My WebApiConfig

```
Public Module WebApiConfig
    Public Sub Register(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)
        ' Servizi e configurazione dell'API Web

        ' Route dell'API Web
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name:="DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
        )

    End Sub
End Module
```

I've tryed to add  `<Route("api/csh/op")>` above GetOperazioni but it had no effect.

Comment: The default route is `api/{controller}/{category}`. If you need a different route syntax, you will need to add it to WebApiConfig. [More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api).

Comment: @Andrew updated the question with my WebApiConfig, how can i add another route to it to access GetOperazioni with api/csh/op?

Comment: Here you have more info about custom routes with VB.NET: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-vb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using attribute routing it is all or nothing.

```
<RoutePrefix("api/csh")>
Public Class CshController
    Inherits ApiController

    'GET api/csh
    <HttpGet()>
    <Route("")>
    Public Function GetValoriCsh(ByVal npv As String, ByVal nc As String) As IEnumerable(Of Cshlvl)
        Dim csh As Cshlvl = New Cshlvl
        Return csh.ValoreCsh(npv, nc)
    End Function

    'GET api/csh/op
    <HttpGet()>
    <Route("op")>
    Public Function GetOperazioni(ByVal npv As String, ByVal nc As String) As IEnumerable(Of OperazioniCsh)
        Dim operazioni As OperazioniCsh = New OperazioniCsh
        Return operazioni.OperazioniCsh(npv, nc)
    End Function
End Class
```

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: that was it, thank you, as i'm new to WebApi is it a good practise to use attribute routing or is it better to route controllers throw WebApiConfig?

Comment: @IgorMytyuk Either is fine. They both have their pros and cons. Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)